# Track objects after Haar cascade opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, haar-classifier

I am tracking vehicle in a video. I am using Haar Cascade for vehicle detection. I have successfully detected vehicle and still working on it. I have two outputs, one with rectangles on original frame and one with filled rectangle drawn on a binary frame of same size.

Please give me idea how to track every vehicle after detection? Should I use Kalman filter or any other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can link detections in trajectories by its positions and
   sizes.
2. Use some correlation method (images of vehicles are not
   changed strongly from frame to frame).
3. Track with using [SIFT](http://docs.opencv.org/master/da/df5/tutorial_py_sift_intro.html) or [SURF](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_surf_intro/py_surf_intro.html).
4. Recognize licence plates on the vehicles and track it.

Comment: thanks for answer. can you give me link to some good SURF or SIFT tutorial? I was searching for this. but couldn't find.

Comment: I added links to SURF and SIFT tutorials.

Comment: is to possible to track multiple types of vehicles, like cars, jeeps, bus. etc?

Comment: Why not? Car doesn't change strongly between two frames. So you can use many methods to link seprate detections of the car to one trajectory.